# Which index is needed for a Mongoid order_by and find_by query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoid

To find the most recently created user named "Jeff",

```
User.order_by(created_at: :desc)
    .find_by(name: "Jeff")
```

Which indexes should be created for this query? Would it be 2 indexes, on `created_at` and `name`?

Or a compound index on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'll have to use a compound index on both for the query to be covered.

It is sometimes possible to use [Index Intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort) to use multiple indexes to fulfill queries, but one of the restrictions is that

> Index intersection does not apply when the sort() operation requires an index completely separate from the query predicate.

which is the case for this query.